# What do I call a 2 dimensional surface bound by edges that are line segments or circular arcs?

Tags: geometry

What do I call a 2d surface similar to a polygon, but more general in the sense that edges can be circular arcs as well?

The generalized name should allow for:

- Arbitrary number of countable edges
- Edge lengths may vary
- Arcs and Lines can be used in any combination
- Surface may be concave

Comment: I've run into this shape before with respect to the linked "Conveyor Belt Alphabet". Haven't figured out what it's called. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cb6f/f99a535f2172d2deea327b4199c72564330f.pdf?_ga=1.17714685.534639534.1493068636

Comment: @LarryB. Nice one, however you always have arcs following lines. Which means its not quite general enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Circular-arc polygons*. E.g.,

[image: Def]

> Wang, Z. J., Lin, X., Fang, M. E., Yao, B., Guan, H., & Guo, M. (2012). RE2L: An Efficient Output-sensitive Algorithm for Computing Boolean Operation on Circular-arc Polygons. arXiv:1211.0729.

[image: Fig5]

Same definition used in other papers, e.g.,

> Howell, Louis H. "Numerical conformal mapping of circular arc polygons." *Journal of computational and applied mathematics* 46.1-2 (1993): 7-28.