# What is the name of the domain that covers all rotations of a polygon?

Tags: geometry, polygons, plane-geometry

Given a polygon $P$ and an angle $\theta$, what is the name of the domain obtained from the union of all the rotations of the polygon from 0 to $\theta$?

That is, if we call $R(\alpha, v_0)P$ the rotation of polygon $P$ around point $v_0$ and angle $\alpha$, What's the name of the domain

$$D = \bigcup_{\alpha \in [0,\theta]} R(\alpha, v_0)P$$

Clearly $D$ is a circular-arc polygon.

It sounds like a reachability problem, but I couldn't find a name for it.

Examples on triangles, $D$ is the union of the gray and the dark-yellow regions:

[image: Rotated trinagles]

Comment: I don't think it has a name. It is a [circular-arc polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250563/237), but that is a class wider than your shapes $D$.

Comment: thank you, that is a start. It still doesn't say anything about it being created form a rotated polygon.